# Is there a disorder similar to dyscalculia but only for time/date arithmetic? (also memory)

Tags: developmental-psychology

Something that might be used to describe an individual who:

- can perform arithmetic at an advanced level (e.g. post graduate)
- does not generally struggle with memory
- can easily remember the relative ordering of past events
- is young/not at an advanced age
- struggles to perform basic calculations when the numbers represent units of time (e.g. "it is 6pm, what time will it be 5 hours from now?")
- has difficulty reading an analogue clock
- has difficulty remembering the year/date an event occurred
- has difficulty remembering the current date/their age

Comment: What is the reason for this question? Does there need to be?

Comment: Because I've become aware of an interesting collection of traits with a vague similarity to a named developmental disorder and I would like to learn more/know if it has ever been discussed or researched before. I cannot understand why you are having this reaction to my question on a platform used to exchange information regarding cognitive science through a question and answer process.

Comment: We just expect questions on this site to be motivated and framed within one of the fields in cognitive sciences. In other words, including how you have become aware of this collection of traits, how you have observed them and the specific overlap and diversion with dyscalculia would improve your question. Include more specifcially where the existing diagnosis does not apply, and where it does.

Comment: Perhaps Stevens reaction was in part triggered by self help questions being off-topic here. You are probably describing either yourself or someone close to you. We cannot perform diagnoses in silico. If you are worried in any way, we recommend you to seek professional help.

Comment: To clarify, my goal is not to diagnose anyone, or to seek out some kind of treatment/help. I am aware that rendering a diagnosis is not something to be done online and that is not where my interests are. I've simply observed these traits in individuals, and after discussing the idea with others, would like to know if this is a concept that has been previously considered or researched. I am curious about what such a disorder might indicate about how the brain develops/processes time/may have redundant systems for performing arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dyscalculia includes or at least is closely related to difficulty reading an analog clock, [says Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyscalculia) citing a PhD thesis which I haven't checked myself. Also, without a citation this time, Wikipedia adds "Difficulty with time, directions, recalling schedules, sequences of events. Difficulty keeping track of time. Frequently late or early." General comorbidity with ADHD is also mentioned.

There are obscure forms of marginal dyslexia (there was a question here recently), so I don't doubt there are probably obscure/marginal forms of dyscalculia that may or may not have received much attention separately. Research into the heterogeneity of dyscalculia is a fairly recent endeavor. Quoting from a [recent paper on the topic](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5209352/)

> time processing [is] more often affected by number processing than vice versa. (e.g., Cappelletti et al., 2011) Also space and time have demonstrated to exert reciprocal influence on each other.

So what you describe (time but not general number dyscalculia) is probably fairly rare. The more focused article of interest by [Cappelletti et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21807010) looks only at acquired cases, following brain lesions; however if my analogy with marginal forms of dyslexia holds, my crystal ball says eventually the developmental version will be found and studied.

As for the final part of your list of symptoms, I don't know how researched the relationship between remembering times and manipulating them is, but it seems obvious that the former can affect the latter.

References (spelled out):

- Ulf Träff et al., Heterogeneity of Developmental Dyscalculia: Cases with Different Deficit Profiles, Front Psychol. 2016; 7: 2000. doi:  10.3389/fpsyg.2016.02000
- Cappelletti M., Freeman E. D., Cipolotti L. (2011). Numbers and time doubly dissociate. Neuropsychologia 49, 3078–3092. doi: 10.1016/j.neuropsychologia.2011.07.014

Comment: Also, cool stuff worth mentioning here, although not directly answering any part of the question, [TNS synaesthesia](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25300202).